# I want ziparchive or other php script to download all files from a folder in zip

Tags: php, mysql, html, zip, unzip

```
<table id="b" class="table table-hover" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <th>Serial No</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Point ID</th>
                <th>CV</th>
                <th>USI</th>
                <th>Reference</th>
                <th>Academic Certificate</th>
                <th>Training Documents</th>
                <th>Pay Slips</th>
                <th>Work Pictures</th>
                <th>Other Documents</th>
                <th>Work Documents</th>
                <th>Applicants Form</th>
                <th>Employer Form</th>
                <th>Action</th>

            </tr>                   
        <?php

            $result = mysql_query("select * from student_portal");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))                    
    {
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['student_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['point_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cv']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usi']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['reference']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['academic_certificate']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['training_documents']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Pay_slips']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['work_pictures']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['other_documents']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['work_documents']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['declaraction_form']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['declaraction_employer']; ?></td>               
        </tr>
```

Here is the code, I want to download all file in a zip format. In zip file all in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to create a row HTML file of the output and run it through a php zipper function.

Here's one to get you started

```
function unzip_file($location,$newLocation){
if(exec("unzip $location",$arr)){
    mkdir($newLocation);
    for($i = 1;$i< count($arr);$i++){
        $file = trim(preg_replace("~inflating: ~","",$arr[$i]));
        copy($location.'/'.$file,$newLocation.'/'.$file);
        unlink($location.'/'.$file);
    }
    return TRUE;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

}